# Microsoft V.S can't start debugging because the debug target is missing

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am having a problem running my Windows Application Forms in Visual Basic. It keeps on giving me this error:

( Visual studio cannot start debugging because the debug target'C:\Users\hp\ducuments\visual studio2010\
Projects\Crystaltest2\Crystaltest2\bin\Debug\Crystaltest2.exe' is missing. please build the project and retry,
 or set the OutputPath ans AssemblyName properties appropriately to point at the correct location for the target assembly).

I have tried to build the project but i cant get anything from it also I tried to copy the code in another project but it did not work.
 Can someone please assist me with steps to solve this issue. I am using Visual Basic/ Visual Studio 2010

i think that the problem is the target framework, 
so when i build in **target framework 4** it works but i must use **target framework 3.5** for my ***crystalReport.*** 
But when i built it in 3.5 it doesn't work !!!

any suggestions please

Thank you

Comment: Do you have .NET 3.5 installed on your machine?  If I remember correctly, it's not by default on Windows 10 these days.  To check, open the Programs & Features applet (get to it any way you like, including from the Settings app under Apps -> Apps & Features, where you'll find a link on the right-hand side) and then click 'Turn Windows features on or off' on the left-hand side.

Comment: Questions like this need to document the installed anti-malware product.

Comment: it s by default on windows 7